# continuity of a map

Tags: algebraic-topology

let B be the closed unit ball & D the open unit ball.
If g is a continuous function from B$\rightarrow R$ can one find always a continuous function from $R^2 \rightarrow R$  such that f=g on B?The same question applies to D.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Do you have any thoughts on this problem? It's better to include them to get answers. At least for the case of the open ball (which is somewhat easier)?

Comment: I was thinking of using Tieze's Extension theorem since R^2 is normal

Answer (score 0):

For the closed ball, think about extending $g$ "radially" when $\|x\| \ge 1$ (there is no need to use complicated theorems about the normality of $\mathbb{R}^2$):
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
g(x) & x \|x\| \le 1 \\
g(\frac{x}{\|x\|}) & \|x\| > 1
\end{cases}$$
(make sure to understand why this is continuous)

For the open ball, find a function that blows up near the boundary of $D$, for example $\frac{1}{1-\|x\|}$.